# Error changing password in active directory

Tags: spring-boot, active-directory

I am currently developing an applikation with spring boot. User for this application are read from an MS Active Directory. While reading all users from the AD and authenticating via Spring Boot Security Configuration are working fine, I've got some trouble changing a users password.

I dont want the users of my application to login to my domain controller to change their initial passwords. So this should be possible via the application itself.
Currently I tried to use the code below but am I getting an exeption when trying it:

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
[LDAP: error code 50 - 00002098: SecErr: DSID-03150F93, problem 4003 (INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS), data 0 ]; nested exception is javax.naming.NoPermissionException: [LDAP: error code 50 - 00002098: SecErr: DSID-03150F93, problem 4003 (INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS), data 0 ]; remaining name 'cn=testing user'

```
public void changeUserPassword(String username, String oldPassword, String newPassword) {
    byte[] encodedNewPassword = encode(newPassword);
    ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[1];
    mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("UnicodePwd", encodedNewPassword));

String base = "OU=someOtherOU,OU=someOu,DC=domain,DC=dom";
String userCN = "CN="+username;
String userDN = userCN + "," + base;
    LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
    contextSource.setUrl("ldap://my-domain.com:389");
    contextSource.setBase(base);
    contextSource.setUserDn(userDN);
    contextSource.setPassword(oldPassword);
    contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();

    LdapTemplate ldapTemplate = new LdapTemplate(contextSource);

    ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(UserCN, mods);
}

private byte[] encode(String password) {
    String quotedPassword = "\"" + password + "\"";
    char[] unicodePassword = quotedPassword.toCharArray();
    byte[] passwordArray = new byte[unicodePassword.length * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < unicodePassword.length; i++) {
        passwordArray[i * 2 + 1] = (byte) (unicodePassword[i] >>> 8);
        passwordArray[i * 2] = (byte) (unicodePassword[i] & 0xff);
    }
    return passwordArray;
}
```

This code will result in the error I already posted. Since I have little experience with using ldap protocoll and active directory, I dont know what I am doing wrong here.

Is there a mistake in my code?
Or does this point to some faulty configuration within the active directory? (I used the default values for the "create new user"-wizard within the Active Directory Management Tool) - for example: Do I have to provide some special permissions to the user?

Some help would be really nice.

Answer (score 0):

AD needs encrypted connection LDAPS when you change unicodePassword.
If you haven't set up LDAPS yet on AD, the following URL might help you.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoftrservertigerteam/2017/04/10/step-by-step-guide-to-setup-ldaps-on-windows-server/

Comment: Thank you very much for that information. I will read the link later, but this really could help me a lot here! :-)

Comment: Hello again.
I now tried your solution, but at the moment I seem to fail with the certificate. As state in the link you provided, I created a certificate with the ldap certification tool. I exported that and added it to the java certification store (both the installed jre and the jre within the installed jdk.) When I am trying to connect to ldaps://my.dom:636 I will and up with an exception all the time: 
[...]
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: my.dom:636
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection or outbound has closed

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Addtion (run out of characters for comment): The code stayed the same as posted with the exception of ldap url parameter

Comment: Does the command "keytool -list -keystore <your jre's keystore path>" show your Active Directory' s certificate? If so, it has your AD server's full computer name?

Comment: yeay, I seem to have done some copy&paste mistake here.  Before doing some more mistakes. What is the full computer name to put here? That sounds stupid, i know, but I am a little bit confused here.
Is it the acutal pc name of the server? (for example my-windows-pc)
Is it the domain name (for example my.domain)
Is it the ADs FQDN (for example mydomain.dom)

Or is it some combination of that?

Sorry for my stupidity today. Have had a hard weekend. May thats it.

Comment: I'm very sorry for having confused you with my poor English. The full computer name is included in the command 'net config workstation'. The certificate's common name(CN) should be it. I just wanted you to check that. I didn't want to put your computer name here.

Comment: I think your english is fine and your anwsers help me a lot. Its just some bad understanding and low experience with AD on my site. While i have been a Software developer for ten years now, I was never in need of administrating an AD or a ldap. I will give it a try later and leave another comment if it works now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hm, I tried it with multiple things now, but the spring boot server will always fail the execute ldaps. I am always gettings an SSLException caused bei SocketException (socket closed).
There must be something wrong with the way i am doing it.

I am creating a certifiacte with the AD CS of my server like in the tutorial you initially posted. Then I export it and import it to all java cacert-files my server provides. There will be now error message while doing it and the cert is present within the cacert files.
Executing the app (on the server) via java -jar will run into the error.

Comment: Lets assume the following structur for an example.
My AD uses the structur dc=my,dc=ad. The computer name would be SomeServer. So the net stat command will provide me the "full computer name" SomeServer.my.ad
What should the certs CN and DN look like?

Is there anything else I might have been done wrong?

Comment: Sorry for delayed reply. Have you already fixed this problem? In your case, your certs CN should be SomeServer.my.ad. Other attributes are less important.

Comment: I am sorry, too. I used my vacation for a hiking trip. No internet, no smartphone and all that stuff. Is really nice for some time :-)
Yes, i fixed the problem. The CN was missing the 'www' in front of the domain apparently. After naming it www.my.server it just worked fine. I was so used to not type www. in front of an url that I totally missed it.